# OCI SDK For DotNet Hangs When Doing Requests

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I followed the example in described by Oracle here: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/dot-net-examples/51.3.0/vault/ListSecrets.cs.html and when I try any of the commands it sends a request and receives a response back with a response code of 200, but it does nothing after receiving a response. It just hangs. And I also only have 1 Vault and 1 Secret in that Vault.  The logs stop with the log:

> Setting Property Value from Header

Has any experienced this issue before?

I tried checking if it was the authentication, tried googling and tried other services like the KMSVaultService. I am expecting to get a value back when I call the ListSecrets method and for it not to hang.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update the dependency packages. After doing that it started to work again